# Pending friend requests on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I want to see my all pending friend requests, which are sent by me on Facebook. I also want to see those people who have not accepted my friend request. Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

[Facebook now has a built-in page where it will list all pending friend requests.](https://www.facebook.com/friends/requests/?fcref=jwl&outgoing=1) The page is at: https://www.facebook.com/friends/requests/?fcref=jwl&outgoing=1

[image: Screenshot of above-mentioned page.]

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has no such feature. If someone rejects your friend request, [you will not be notified](http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=119703577130):

> When you receive a friend request from people you don't wish to be friends with, you can decline by simply selecting "Ignore." Doing so will remove the request from your Requests list. They will not be notified that their friend request was declined, but they will be able to send you another friend request in the future.

The only solution I can think of is that you keep a list of people you have sent friend requests to. Periodically, go through the list, and visit those profiles. If the button for sending a friend request is available, it means your previous request was rejected. If the person has not responded to the request yet, you will see a "Friend request sent" message.

Comment: Care to share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the requests that you have sent using this app: https://www.facebook.com/PendingFriendRequestsApp

You can't view the people that have declined your friend request. Also remember, if you get a friend request from someone and you decline them, facebook will ask you if you know the person outside of facebook.  If you choose no, facebook may block the person from sending out other requests for up to a month.  Obviously, this can be done to you as well, so if someone has not accepted your request you might consider canceling the request so you don't get blocked from requesting.

Comment: it is fake and donot working

Comment: It works fine, go directly to the app.. https://apps.facebook.com/friendrequests/  hit "bulk upload", when the new page comes up, it shows 3 steps. Click> "Get Friend Request Data"  2. copy all the text 3. paste it into the box and click "load friend requests".  Just worked for me a minute ago.

Comment: The app above no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found a loophole to see pending friend requests on Facebook Timeline. Although Facebook does show you with all the friend requests received, there is no direct means to access the request you have sent from your account. But you can still keep track of them using the Facebook’s “Download Your Information” option. Follow:

1. Go to your '**Account Settings**'
2. Click on '**Download a Copy of your Facebook data**' on bottom of page.
3. Select '**expanded archive**' from the link below.
4. After entering your Password, click on '**Start My Archive**'
5. Once the archive is ready, you will receive an email. Now you need to **download** the archive from the link. (Usually takes 1 to 2 hours)
6. Extract downloaded zip file and Open **index.html**
7. Then navigate to “**Pending friend requests**” link. Click that link, now you can see the whole pending friend requests list on 'Pending Sent Friend Requests' head. It will also shows you the 'Pending Received Friend Requests'. You can also view friends whom you have deleted from your account.

You're done! c:

For detailed tutorial with screenshots, visit:http://www.sociobits.org/2013/04/view-your-pending-friend-requests-on-facebook-timeline-may-2013.html